# Display Notification in Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarm, notificationmanager

Ok, I have set up an alarm manager to activate every 10 seconds.  I tested this with a toast and it worked great but I want a notification to display instead.  I cannot get this code to compile though.  All of the errors occur after the //NOTIFICATION line up until wl.release();

ERRORS:

```
The constructor NotificationCompat.Builder(Alarm) is undefined
The constructor Intent(Alarm, Class<StatusOfChild>) is undefined
The method create(Context) in the type TaskStackBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Alarm)
The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Alarm
```

CODE:

```
package com.sjjgames.abortionappnoads;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

                // Put here YOUR code.
                //NOTIFICATION
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, StatusOfChild.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(StatusOfChild.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(9011, mBuilder.build());

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }




 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `context`  instead of `this` for all Method.

Like This Way.

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                            .setContentTitle("My notification")
                            .setContentText("Hello World!");
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, StatusOfChild.class);
                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(StatusOfChild.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(9011, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: that fixes the first problem but I still get the last three errors

Comment: This fixes another error but I still have an error at this line: Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, StatusOfChild.class); and this line: NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: all changes are done see my editable answer & use my code instead of your

Comment: & why i have to learn how classes, fields and OOP works. if you already learn then why do you ask this type of question

Comment: Yeah I was getting a little frustrated and I feel stupid now for not seeing this earlier -Thanks for the help